# How to incorporate SASS from installed Bulma package into Angular app?

Tags: css, angular, npm, sass

I'm attempting to introduce Bulma in my project. According to the docs, the recommended approach is to obtain it using NPM.

> yarn add bulma

Further [down the docs](https://bulma.io/documentation/overview/start/), they show an example with the following lines of code.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.6.2/css/bulma.min.css">
<script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/js/all.js"></script>
```

As far I understand, it's superfluous to NPM the package if we CDN it (and reversely, if we NPM it in, CDN is unnecessary). In this particular case, the users might be behind a bunch of tricky firewalls and such, so it might not work out to apply CDN anyway.I'll have to rely on the package being distributed myself. However, when I remove the lines above, the style disappears and, since there's no information on Bulma's page how to deal with it, I'm not entirely sure how to proceed.

In *node_modules*, there's  a file *bulma.sass* as well as a set of directories with individual asses used to build up the big ass file. I want to make it available in my project. I've seen a whole range of different suggestions when I googled: from simply copying the file into my *src* to a lengthy and compilicated discussion about applying Grunt scripts. Somehow, I feel there's a straightforward way (possibly one that I've even seen) but that I'm too confused to recognize it.

How do I transpile styles from installed packages (residing in *node_modules*) into my Angular application's *src* and/or *dist* folders?

Bonus question is how I should go about the FontAwesome linkage when used for Bumla (unless it's the same way as it's set for other frameworks, in which case, I can google it myself or ask another question.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to declare the custom styles and scripts on the .angular-cli.json

Example:

```
 ...
 "prefix": "app",
 "styles": [
     "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
 ]
 ...
```

An alternative to reuse the style file already present in the Angular structure and import the external style file as needed.

Example:

```
 ...
 "prefix": "app",
 "styles": [
     "styles.scss"
 ]
 ...
```

Then, in *styles.scss*:

```
@import "../node_modules/bulma/bulma.sass"
```

That also allows for cherry-picking the parts of Bulma that are actually required (allowing for additional optimization of the file size).

Comment: I see. My consideration regards the fact that those are technically speaking **outside** of the application's root level. It worries me and I'm too ignorant to judge if it's a no-go or if I can do it safely.

Comment: Since you don't need to publish the node_modules, it seems that Webpack get those **outside** files and get them all together to generate the styles bundle.

Comment: All right. Makes sense - as long as the local file structure works out, Webpack can reach and grab it, I should be fine. Now, how about FontAwesome? I'm sensing that there's a bit different approach for that since it's not a style. (The link targets a JS file but I expected some kind of font thingy or such and got all precautious...)

Comment: The Font files (.eot, .ttf, .woff and .woff2) are loaded by the fontawesome.css, so you can just load it in the same way you loaded the bulma.css.

In my environment I download the font-awesome zip, extract at assets folder and load from there in the .angular-cli.json